# Power bi return non existing rows as 0 in a matrix

Tags: powerbi, dax

We have a dataset in which there is data for only several months. So for example January is in, March is in and June is in. Then a matrix is formed with the data.

```
 january    february    march    april    may    june    july
 345                    452                      657
```

So our data looks like this

```
Months      value
january     345
march       452
june        657
```

We want to average the values in this matrix. So sum(values)/months. We have tried a lot with Power bi DAX but have not yet found the solution.

Now the average that comes out is the following

```
(345 + 452 + 657) / 3  =  484,6
```

While what we want is

```
(345 + 452 + 657) / 7  =  207,7
```

Comment: How do you choose 7? Why do you include July but not August and how would you know to do that from your data table?

Answer (score 0):

Matrix is specially designed to show only the column or row that has a value on it. It will not show null or no values on it.

But, if you Create a Measure and add + 0 to the Measure Formula then it should show the value. An Example would look like this

**# Sales= DISTINCTCOUNT(tbl_SalesHistory[SaleID]) + 0**